# Correct way to call a method of a subclass from another subclass

Tags: python

I am working to understand Python and I am currently working on an Employee program. The program is fairly straight forward but I have run into a snag. I am attempting to call one of my other subclass's methods from within a subclass. Both of them are inheriting from the same class but I am not sure what the syntax is. I figured I could demonstrate what I am trying to do without posting all of my code. So here is a shortened version of my program:

```
class Employee:
  num_of_emps = 0
  raise_amount = 1

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.id = id
    self.pay = pay


class Manager(Employee):
  raise_amount = 1.08

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup = None):
    super().__init__(first, last, id, pay)
    if emp_under_sup is None:
      self.emp_under_sup = []
    else:
      self.emp_under_sup = emp_under_sup

  def add_emp(self, emp):
    if emp not in self.emp_under_sup:
      self.emp_under_sup.append(emp)

class Supervisor(Employee):
  raise_amount = 1.06

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup = None):
    super().__init__(first, last, id, pay)
    if emp_under_sup is None:
      self.emp_under_sup = []
    else:
      self.emp_under_sup = emp_under_sup

  def add_emp(self, emp):
    if emp not in self.emp_under_sup:
      self.emp_under_sup.append(emp)
      Manager.add_emp(self, emp)
```

As you can see, in the Supervisor class under the add_emp method I am attempting to call the add_emp method of the Manager class. That way, whenever I create a new employee and add it the Supervisors emp_under_sup list it will also be added to the Manager's emp_under_sup list. The idea being that every employee should be supervised by a Manager without having to explicitly sate it.

In other words if I say:

```
mng1 = Manager('Jose', 'Federosa', 1, 80000)
sup1 = Supervisor('Jake', 'Derber', 2, 70000)
mng1.add_emp(sup1)
dev1 = Developer('Rob', "M", 3, 60000, 'Python and Java')
sup1.add_emp(dev1)
mng1.info()
```

Then I want the output to be:

```
Manager's ID: 1 
Full name: Jose Federosa 
Salary: 80000 
Employee's under supervision: Jake Derber Rob M
```

However, calling Manager.add_emp(self, emp) from inside the add_emp method of the Supervisor class is not working like I would expect it to. Can someone explain why this won't work?

Comment: The object only has one `emp_under_sup` attribute. Both methods are adding to the same list.

Comment: You are calling `add_emp` on the Manager class, but it would need to be an instance of it. For that you would have to pass the Manager instance into the Supervisor object, for example when you call `add_emp` on the Supervisor instance, because in your current structure, the objects have no knowledge about who is their respective supervisor/manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each employee a `manager` attribute, and set this in `Manager.add_emp()`. Then `Supervisor.add_emp()` can get the supervisor's manager, and call `add_emp()` on that manager.

```
class Employee:
  num_of_emps = 0
  raise_amount = 1

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.id = id
    self.pay = pay
    self.manager = None

  def set_manager(self, mgr):
    self.manager = mgr

class Manager(Employee):
  raise_amount = 1.08

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup = None):
    super().__init__(first, last, id, pay)
    if emp_under_sup is None:
      self.emp_under_sup = []
    else:
      self.emp_under_sup = emp_under_sup

  def add_emp(self, emp):
    if emp not in self.emp_under_sup:
      self.emp_under_sup.append(emp)
      emp.set_manager(self)

class Supervisor(Employee):
  raise_amount = 1.06

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup = None):
    super().__init__(first, last, id, pay)
    if emp_under_sup is None:
      self.emp_under_sup = []
    else:
      self.emp_under_sup = emp_under_sup

  def add_emp(self, emp):
    if emp not in self.emp_under_sup:
      self.emp_under_sup.append(emp)
      if self.manager:
          self.manager.add_emp(emp)
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Wondering now, of a slick way to expand this concept such that an employee can not be created until a manager has been created. Then each subsequent employee would be assigned a manager. Maybe the best way to go about that would be to change the Employee class to manager and define a separate employee subclass?

Comment: What about the first employee?

Comment: No, Employee is the correct base class. Managers are types of employees, and subclassing is how we represent "is-a" relationships.

Comment: Probably the right thing would be for the manager to be an optional parameter to the Employee constructor. But it can be left out for an employee with no manager (like the CEO).